# Batch script to backup and rename a file acting strangely

Tags: batch-file, backup

Got a problem that is confusing me, I am trying to get a file that is a copy of a master to have the date appended to it and moved to a folder while a new copy of the master is created in the main folder. My steps are as follows:

1. Rename > XX-XXX-001-WorkingVisualisation.nwf to XX-XXX-001-WorkingVisualisation-[todays date].nwf
2. Move XX-XXX-001-WorkingVisualisation-[todays date].nwf to /Superseded_NWD-NWF/
3. Copy with New Name > XX-XXX-000-MasterVisualisation.nwf to XX-XXX-001-WorkingVisualisation.nwf

And what I done:

```
echo on


for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "15-483-001 Working Visualisation.nwf" "15-483-001 Working Visualisation "%%d-%%e-%%f.nwf


move /Y C:\Users\jhardman\Desktop\testarea\*.nwf C:\Users\jhardman\Desktop\testarea\Superseded_NWD-NWF


copy /Y "C:\Users\jhardman\Desktop\testarea\Master\*.nwf" "C:\Users\jhardman\Desktop\testarea\15-483-001 Working Visualisation.nwf"


end
```

Originally the master sat at the top level but I moved it into its own area after it kept getting dragged into the superseded folder. Also the strangest thing is that if I run it without having a WorkingVisualisation in the top level a back up with date is still created in the superseded folder!

I don't know what that is from and also if the ones that do get back up are really the ones that are.

Comment: The quotation marks in the `rename` command line must enclose the entire paths/names; the new name does not fulfill this; in the `move` command line the quotes are missing at all...

Comment: Ah must of deleted them at some point when messing around with paths. Strange not getting a date at all now, bit confused with the date thing

Comment: First thing it hould be `@echo on` secondly there should be a quotation mark here `for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "15-483-001 Working Visualisation.nwf" "15-483-001 Working Visualisation "%%d-%%e-%%f.nwf`. So that would make it  `for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do rename "15-483-001 Working Visualisation.nwf" "15-483-001 Working Visualisation %%d-%%e-%%f.nwf"`